# 384x384px tile to diplay at 384x384px on map (retina)

Tags: openlayers-3, highdpi, hidpi

I serve TMS tile with in two flavours: 256px or 384px through renderd option scale=1.5.
With Openlayers 3, the only way I found to display these 384px tiles their original size is to transform the canvas context like this:

```
map.getViewport().getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext("2d").setTransform(1.5, 0, 0, 1.5, -w, -h);
```

I think it's not the proper way to go, so what would be the right one?

I played a bit with a special ol.tilegrid but with no success, see here:
https://jsfiddle.net/yvecai/owwc5bo8/8/

The output I aim for is on the right map.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a special tile grid or to apply any canvas scaling. All you need to do is set the `tilePixelRatio` of the source properly, which would be `1.5` in your case:

```
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: "http://www5.opensnowmap.org/base_snow_map_high_dpi/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?debug",
    attributions: [/* ... */],
    tilePixelRatio: 1.5
  })
```

Also note that your expectation of the result is wrong. I updated your fiddle to compare the standard 256px tiles (on the right) with the hidpi 384px tiles (on the left). If you are viewing the fiddle on a hidpi display, you'll notice the difference. https://jsfiddle.net/owwc5bo8/9/

Comment: Don't say my expectation of the result is wrong, I may just have badly expressed myself :)

I'd like the user to have the possibility to choose either a x1 or x1.5 magnified map, whatever the pixelratio of his/her device is. Maybe it's a questionable or uncommon design choice, but it's mine. I'm not after sharpness here.

I tried the updated jsfiddle on my device with pixelratio=2 or chromium dev tools with a pixelratio of 1.5, with no difference in the actual visible scale 'Paris' have the same length on screen.

Comment: Is there no way to display 384*384 px tile 1:1 with a pixel ratio of 1?

Comment: It is possible, but you'll need a custom tile grid and view configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize:

- If you want to display high-dpi tiles on a mobile device with good sharpness, use tilePixelRatio :
  https://jsfiddle.net/owwc5bo8/9/
- If you want to display tiles with a size differnet than 256x256, create a proper ol.tilegrid, and a proper ol.view:

  https://jsfiddle.net/owwc5bo8/12/

  ```
  var extent = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857').getExtent();
  var tileSizePixels = 384;
  var tileSizeMtrs = ol.extent.getWidth(extent) / 384;
  var resolutions = [];
  for (var i = -1; i <= 20; i++) {
  resolutions[i] = tileSizeMtrs / (Math.pow(2, i));
  }

  var tileGrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
  extent: extent,
  resolutions: resolutions,
  tileSize: [384, 384]
  });

  var center = ol.proj.fromLonLat(
  ol.proj.toLonLat([2, 49], 'EPSG:4326'),
  'EPSG:3857');
  var zoom = 5;

  var view1 = new ol.View({
  center: center,
  zoom: zoom,
  maxResolution: 40075016.68557849 / 384
  });
  ```